# Plot multiple live graph's using data from an updating dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly, live

I have a dict (DATADict) full of data that gets updated constantly, I want to be able to use the data from the dict and have it plot onto a plotly/matplotlib plot. The x will be the time, which is the same for every y value in every subplot. I have tried with matplot and plotly, with matplot I had some success but I couldn't get the axis right and all the points updated at different times (I was using matplot animation), plotly I couldn't even get the same graph to update ot kept opening browsers.

Something that looks like this but with the y axis labled with the name of the key.
[image: Ideal Plot]

This is the code for getting the updating Dictionary.

```
While True:
    Data = {"Temp":10,"Pressure":10} #This is an example of what the dict looks like but its called from another module (There is about 7 keys in total)
    for k,v in Data.items():
        if k not in DATADict.keys():
            fig = plt.fig()
            DATADict.update({k:{"List":[],"Fig":fig}})
        DATADict[k]["List"].append(v)
    #print(DATADict)
```

Anyone got any ideas how I would get the live data from a dict to be displayed on a plot that all has the same Y value's being time?

Comment: Plotly's show() method uses a one shot http request handler that serves an html page for the browser to plot the figure. Any update that could be made after that (ie. using sliders, animations, etc.) requires all the data to be initially loaded, so this exclude live update (except maybe if you plot in a notebook and use a figure widget). You would need a server so that the browser can fetch live data at some intervals. I would recommend using Dash (made by the Plotly team) which embeds a Flask server and allows to use python (and JS) callbacks. See https://dash.plotly.com/